# How to set default shell to WSL bash for SSHing from Windows 10 machine to another Windows 10 machine (VM)?

Tags: windows, bash, ssh, virtual-machine, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am SSHing into a VM on the Windows command line and the WSL bash. However, each time I SSH into the Windows 10 VM (from my own Windows 10 local machine), it opens up the default Windows command prompt as the shell. I would like the WSL bash to open when I use SSH on both the Windows command prompt and WSL bash (on my local machine). Both my local and virtual machines have WSL installed.

I tried: `New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH" -Name DefaultShell -Value "C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe" -PropertyType String -Force` on the Windows Powershell running as administrator but it does not work. All I get back is this, but with no changes:

```
DefaultShell : C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe
PSPath       : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH
PSParentPath : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE
PSChildName  : OpenSSH
PSDrive      : HKLM
PSProvider   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
```

UPDATE: I can change the shell, after I SSH into the Windows 10 VM, by running `bash.exe` from `C:\Windows\System32`. However, it still starts as the default Windows command line when I first SSH.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the same command:

`New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH" -Name DefaultShell -Value "C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe" -PropertyType String -Force`

on the virtual machine running Windows 10.

Comment: This seems to work, but is it a global setting, or does it only apply to the user running the command?

Comment: have you noticed that `sftp` fails after you run the command above?